# c# lambda reading each row with GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: c#, lambda, group-by

This is the working query i was using in my management studio.

```
SELECT TOP 5 productCode, SUM(productSales) AS sales
FROM     sellingLog
WHERE  (salesYear = '2014')
GROUP BY productCode
ORDER BY sales DESC
```

I want to convert the query above into lambda, but i can't seems to make it works. the lambda still lacks of order by and select the productCode

```
var topProducts = sellingLog
       .Where(s => s.salesYear == 2014)
       .GroupBy(u => u.productCode)
       .Select(b => b.Sum(u => u.productSales)).Take(5)
       .ToList();

foreach(var v in topProduct)
{
   //reading 'productCode' and 'sales' from each row
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var topProducts = sellingLog
       .Where(s => s.salesYear == 2014)
       .GroupBy(u => u.productCode)
       .Select(g => new { productCode = g.Key, sales = g.Sum(u => u.productSales) })
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.productCode)
       .Take(5)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response, just out of curiosity. how to differentiate the "Key" if i group by 2 columns?

Comment: in that case `Key` would be of anonymous type, and you'd be able to use another property access to get one of the columns. e.g. after grouping by `new { u.productCode, u.year }` you'd be able to use `g.Key.productCode` and `g.Key.year` later on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.Key` with group by to get `productCode`

```
var topProducts = sellingLog
   .Where(s => s.salesYear == 2014)
   .GroupBy(u => u.productCode)
   .Select(b => new {u.Key, b.Sum(u => u.productSales)}).Take(5)
   .OrderByDescending(b=>b.Sales) 
   .ToList();
```